# Eager Load indirect associations Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Associations are below:

```
#app/models/pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet_store
end

#app/models/pet_store.rb
class PetStore < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pets, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy
end

#app/models/employee.rb
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet_store
end
```

I want to do something like so which would cause an `N + 1` error:

```
@pets = Pet.where(species: "Dog").includes(:pet_store)
@pets.each do |pet|
  pet.pet_store.employees.each do |employee|
    puts employee.name
  end
end
```

This causes an N+1 error because a query must be made for each `employee`.  I would like to `eager load` the indirect associated `employees`. However, I cannot simply `includes(:employees)` because a `pet` has no direct association to `employees`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can with:

```rb
@pets = Pet.includes(:pet_store => :employees)
```

The Rails Guide on the Query Language is great. Here's the [docs on eager-loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations).

Comment: all is not required, you can directly do ``@pets = Pet.includes(:pet_store => :employees)``

Comment: Can I use this in the view? Because I tried with no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42606013/why-rails-controller-is-not-including-actually-associations?noredirect=1#comment72345912_42606013

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't be loading data in the view, if you can help it. Looks like your issue might be the `attr_accessor` (which I've added as a comment to your question).