# How to eager load associations into an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations, react-rails

In Model I have:

```
class CalendarItem < Resource
  belongs_to :schedule

  has_many :people
  has_many :documents

  acts_as_list scope: :schedule, column: :visual_position

  validates :schedule, :title, presence: true
end
```

Then in controller:

```
class ScheduleController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @calendar_items = CalendarItem.where(schedule: @schedule).includes(:people, :documents)
  end

  ...
end
```

In the view I'm rendering a react_component with react-rails (but that should make any difference):

```
= react_component('CalendarItemsList', calendar_items: @calendar_items)
```

However it does not pass the associated data to the view (react_component), only main model.

I have experienced this before, with non-react front-end, and it didn't work either. What could be wrong?

Comment: Does it pass an empty array, nil, or throw an error?

Comment: I can use the @caledar_items, but it does not include the associations people and documents. Thanks

Comment: Oh, that should be easy.  Try `CalendarItem.includes(<criteria>).where(<criteria>)`.  You have the order backward.

Comment: Tried it with no luck :( doesn't change it, still only the main model

Comment: Does the order matter really? I thought it didn't

Comment: I was mistaken.  I'm really tired ;).  Anyway, what do you mean when you say it returns the main model?  Does it return the class CalendarItem or does it return a collection that matches your where clause?

Comment: It returns the collection, but I expect each collection item to contain associated modes collection

Comment: `includes` only preloads associations. It does not make a difference as to whether the association is available for the view. Sounds like what you're looking for is a serializer.

Comment: @fylooi, thanks, could you provide an answer? Would appreciate it.

Comment: I followed the guide here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html, but it still doesn't include the association.

Comment: Does your serialiser have the relationships defined in?

Comment: The guides only say about providing `attr_accessor` so I have `attr_accessor :id, :title, :people, :documents`

Comment: What does it return? Usually it'll return the main model, but you'll get the association by navigating with the main model object

Comment: Oh, don't use `attr_accessor` for actual database columns - that's a mistake I've seen a  lot and it tends to mess Active Record's natural accessors up.  Only ever use `attr_accessor` for things that are not database columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the data in in the instance variable but with the serialisation.

The `react_component` view helper will call the `to_json` method on the second argument if it is not a string. In your case: `{calendar_items: @calendar_items}.to_json`, which works recursively, so you want to make sure `@calendar_items.to_json` returns the expected JSON output. You can use `@calendar_items.serializable_hash` for testing it in the `rails console`, it returns a hash, which is more readable for humans.

Or you serialise your data into a string and feed the `react_component` with it.

I dont know Rails 5 serialization but it seems to be similar to [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) so you can include the relationships in the serialised output like: `@calendar_items.to_jso(include: [:documents])`. In ActiveModelSerializers you can specify a serialiser to each class, and specify the relationships on them, those can be included automatically.

So one working solution could be:

```
def show
  calendar_items = CalendarItem.where(schedule: @schedule).includes(:people, :documents)
  @react_component_props = { calendar_items: calendar_items.to_json(include: [:people, :documents]) }
end

= react_component('CalendarItemsList', @react_component_props)
```

A modest tip: you can create a `by_schedule` scope on the CalendarItem model, so later you can use it: `CalendarItem.by_schedule @schedule`

**EDIT**

If you need the data other places in the view then you can use the `as_json` method:

```
def show
  calendar_items_scope = CalendarItem.where(schedule: @schedule).includes(:people, :documents)
  @calendar_items = calendar_items_scope.as_json(include: [:people, :documents])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it works! except now the @react_component_props is part object part json so I need to do some post processing on the front end which is not very neat. Any way to make @react_component_props an object? (including associations) .. I'm guessing that it's because `.to_json` is called twice then (?)

Comment: Forget about it, it works perfect this way: `@calendar_items = calendar_items.as_json(include: [:people, :documents])` where `calendar_items` is local var instead of instance.

Comment: If you can add this to solution, then I can accept it as in use. ... `as_json` here works better

Answer (score 1):

The solution-workaround is to add `as_json` and include the associatiosn there:

```
@calendar_items = CalendarItem.where(schedule: @schedule)
                              .as_json(include: [:people, :documents])
```

This loads / serializes the associations as expected.